# Someone tries to impersonate me on Snapchat

Tags: identity-theft

Someone has created an account in Snapchat with my picture and email address but a different name.

Can you please let me know what to do about it

Comment: Password reset to your email, if that's possible?

Comment: How did someone manage to use your email for registration?

Comment: @Robin Webb: Can you explain in more detail please? Can you post some screenshots (hiding sensitive information) and more evidence?

Comment: @lepe Bad idea, anything useful here will contain personally identifiable information. Please don't encourage people to post PII on this site.

Comment: @Mike: the reason I'm asking it is because an image can explain more than words. There is a chance that there is a misunderstanding. What if by "my picture" he means "my starwars icon" and by "same email address" he means "a similar email address" ? I don't want to encourage him to post personal information, but to make his question easier to understand.

Comment: @lepe I see where you're coming from. Remember though that the point of this site is to build up a knowledge-base that will be useful to people googling for info, so encouraging them to get very specific isn't really in the best interest of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You could dig around on [Snapchat's Privacy page](https://www.snapchat.com/privacy-center). You may be able to contact their support department, prove that you own the email address, and get them to delete the offending account. That said, it's a lot of effort both on your part, and on Snapchat's part, plus you'll have troubles proving, legally speaking, that the account has done something wrong. Plus, whoever did that can make new accounts faster than you can go through the takedown process.

As @Alexander O'Mara suggests, if they really have used your email address to register the account, you might be able to trigger a Password Reset, get into the account, and delete it. (Be careful though, in some countries this is a criminal offence since you're gaining access to an account that you didn't create.)

Personally, unless they're doing something that counts as harassment or identity theft / fraud, I would ignore it.